# Unable to access OrangeHRM application after installation

Tags: apache, webserver, orangehrm

I have recently installed an OrangeHRM instance on CentOs 7 machine. But after the installation, I am unable to access the application.

When I go to the URL, it points me to default apache test page.  I feel like it not been able to read the file in /var/www/html folder.

I have used [this link](https://github.com/akashkroy/OrangeHRM-in-CentOS-7) to install the application on CentOs machine,

Answer (score 0):

the link you followed is mixed up, the easiest way is to do the following:

```
$ mv orangehrm-3.3.2/* /var/www/html/orangehrm
```

then `http://localhost/orangehrm`

althought the installation in the link is not complete.